# Azure VM :: Billing report

Tags: azure, billing, azure-virtual-machine

I am planning to use the virtual machine (preview) feature of windows azure, initially with about 10 virtual machines.

I wonder if the reports of use (for billing purpose) of the windows azure are detailed in relation to the resources used BY EACH of the virtual machines, or if the resources consumed are presented consolidated by type.

My goal is to get the cost of EACH virtual machine (procs allocated bandwidth usage + + storage usage).

That would be possible?

Answer (score 2):

I use the "Download usage details (CSV)" option under account. It will give you an excel sheet that you can format further.

Comment: just to add that this CSV will include information about each separate VM.